# How do I make a JS function that works onolad not work on the first page load.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html page which has a function that would work once the page loads.

```
<body onload="startNow()">
```

This startNow function has a part that refreshes the page if a certain condition is not met and thus causes the function to run again.

```
function startNow() {
    var warning_check = document.getElementsByClassName("warning");
    if (warning_check.length == 0) {
        checkAll(); //another function call
    } else {
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Is there a way i can make this `startNow` function not run the first time this page loads?

Comment: You can save a flag in the localStorage, or in a cookie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easily done with a localStorage

```
function startNow(){
    var warning_check = document.getElementsByClassName("warning");
    if(warning_check.length == 0) {
            checkAll(); //another function call
    } else {
        if (!!localStorage.returningUser){
            window.location.reload();
        } 
    }
    localStorage.returningUser = 'true';
}
```

**EDIT**

the above function still runs for first time users but it won't reload if the code reaches to the reload point.  If you want to code to stop running at all then

```
function startNow(){
    if (!localStorage.returningUser){
        localStorage.returningUser = 'true';
        return false;
    }
    var warning_check = document.getElementsByClassName("warning");
    if(warning_check.length == 0) {
            checkAll(); //another function call
    } else {
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. this put me on the right track. I used sessionStorage instead because I wanted the script not to run the first time for that specific session, because otherwise it would run on every other time the same user opened the application page..